# Missing constraints in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

This view is not constrained vertically: at runtime it will jump to the top unless you add a vertical constraint  The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX). These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections

Comment: show your xml please

Answer (score 0):

add properties to your view like `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` and then give margin to set where ever you want.

and you can find all property of constraint layout here [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the vertical constraint for your view like this

```
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Or you can use the UI Editor from android studio, select the dots on the top and bottom of the view and drag them to the parent, this will set the vertical constraints, you can them edit them directly from xml or UI editor.

[UiEditor Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtsKZ.png)